# Perl split string on literal character \n

Tags: perl

I have a file that is coming to us from an upstream system. It contains a very big string and it contains a literal `\n`. I need to split that big string on literal `\n`.

Here the file that I am geeting:

```
one\nsometing\ntwo\nthree\nmore things\nsome more things
```

As I mentioned above, I need to split this big string on literal `\n` and the expected output will be as follows:

```
one
something
two
three
more things
some more things
```

Comment: perldoc -f split

Comment: @rajashekar, that's quite an unhelpful comment.  You can't assume that a new user would be familiar with all the documentation tools.

Comment: @NathanFellman: A simple google search would take him to the appropriate documentation page. It also introduces `perldoc`.

Comment: @NathanFellman If he is not familiar with the tools to help himself, why would that be an unhelpful comment? Reading the documentation is key to learning Perl. Heck, its how I learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string contains the two characters `\` + `n` and not a newline you need to "escape" the `\` when you use `split`, so `\` becomes `\\`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/perl

my $str='one\nsometing\ntwo\nthree\nmore things\nsome more things';

my @splitted = split/\\n/, $str;    # split on the two characters '\' + 'n'

print join("\n", @splitted) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `split` just like with anything else.

> @x = 'one\nsometing\ntwo\nthree\nmore things\nsome more things';
>
> @split_x = split /\n/, $x;

And then you can print it in a split fashion:

> print join "\n", @split_x;

or even as a one liner

> print join "\n", split /\n/, $x;